# AlarmManager does not work with the app closed or minimized

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to set an alarm in Kotlin, but when I close or minimize the APP it doesn't trigger the alarm (like after 10 minutes onwards), and I need it to be the exact time

the Code is like this

In the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_DOZE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_EXACT_ALARM" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NOTIFICATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NOTIFICATION_BROADCAST_RECEIVER_PERMISSION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@drawable/iconapp"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/iconapp"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyRemedio"
    tools:targetApi="31">

    <activity
        android:name=".splash.view.SplashActivity"
        android:exported="true" />
    <activity
        android:name=".alarmeRemedio.view.FormAlarmeRemedioctivity"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity
        android:name=".remedio.view.FormRemedioActivity"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity
        android:name=".main.view.MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name=".common.receivers.AlarmReceiverNovo"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" />
</application>
```

the Code is like this

`@SuppressLint("ScheduleExactAlarm")
override fun criarAlarme(itemAlarmeIdDate: List) {

```
for (i in itemAlarmeIdDate.indices) {

    val intent = Intent(this, AlarmReceiverNovo::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("id", itemAlarmeIdDate[i].id)

    val pendingIntent =
        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            this,
            itemAlarmeIdDate[i].id,
            intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
        )

    val alarmManager: AlarmManager =
        getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager

    alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(
        AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
        itemAlarmeIdDate[i].date,
        pendingIntent
    )
}
```

}`

I followed the code like this and tested it on Android 12 and 13

Helps him to wake up at the exact time, even if the APP is closed or minimized